# JS : Set Timeout not working with Child Element count

Tags: javascript, timeout

I was wondering what this mysterious output in the chrome dev console is when I run a timeout with a childElementCount and it seems to increment by one each time I re-run the function.

```js
function Eggs(){
var f = document.getElementById("x").childElementCount;
console.log(f);
}
setTimeout(Eggs(), 3000);
/* output should be:
0
8
in the chrome console */
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
    <div>
        <div>
            <div id="x"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

it works just fine and gives me the correct number of children

Comment: Sorry, the title is wrong because before I wasn't getting the correct input at all as opposed to now I'm getting the correct input and another mysterious input.

Comment: setTimeout expects a function as an argument, you are passing in the **result of calling** a function

Comment: The increasing value you see is the return value of `setTimeout`. The dev tools log the result of the last expression you typed. for example: `5 + 7` will output `12`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like next:

```
let eggs = function () {
    let el = document.getElementById('x');
    console.log(el.childElementCount);
};

setTimeout(eggs, 3000);
```

Names of functions MUST be in camelCase!

The `eggs` variable store the function, but `eggs()` - gives to us the result of calling it (what you would have in function return).

```
let eggs = function () {
    return function () {
        let el = document.getElementById('x');
        console.log(el.childElementCount);
    };
};

setTimeout(eggs(), 3000);
```

Comment: why did you change eggs? wasn't it just fine? I mean, the answer is ... remove () from where Eggs() in settimeout ... and you've made like so many changes without justifying any of them

Comment: Why am I removing the () I know it works just tried it but, what's actually happening?

Answer (score 0):

```js
setTimeout(function Eggs(){
var f = document.getElementById('x').childElementCount;
console.log(f)
},3000);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
    <div>
        <div>
            <div id="x"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```